# Excel (If, And, OR) help needed

Tags: excel, if-statement

I have a value 30 in a cell A1 and 18 in A2. In another cell i need something like this:

If A1*20% between 3.5 and 4 then 4
Else A1*20%

Basically i want to check if the 20% of a number is between 3.5 and 4 if it is then i should display 4 and if the 20% is more then 4 then I should display the actual result.
I need to write a single formula and drag it so that the formula will calculate accordingly and display result as "4" or the actual 20%.

I have at least 10k rows with data.

[image]

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
=IF(AND(A1*.2 >=3.5,A1*.2<=4),4,A1*.2)
```

Comment: Thanks Vedenin, that worked.
One more help!
How can i add one more validation?
For E.g.
AND If A1*.2 >= 1 but less then 2, I need result as 2.
I need this additional validation within the formula you provided.
I know this might be easy for you but i am a new user, so thanks for the help.

Comment: @Syed not sure what vedenin did but this was my answer.  Please click the green check mark if it was correct.

Comment: Hey Scott, sorry for the confusion, I was not sure who answered. If possible please reply to my additional question.

Comment: @Syed Another Stack Overflow procedure, Do not change the question or ask a new question in an old question.  You need to make a new post for this. That being said: `=IF(AND(A1*.2 >=3.5,A1*.2<=4),4,IF(AND(A1*.2 >=1,A1*.2<=2),2,A1*.2))`